# How to properly make NonFungibleToken's Unique

Tags: corda

**Question:**

Does the `TokenIdentifier` of a `TokenType` used to build a `NonFungibleToken` have to be a unique string?

**Long-Winded Background:**

The [documentation](https://training.corda.net/libraries/tokens-sdk/) clearly outlines that “It is, in fact, the responsibility of the developer to ensure that no two instances of an `NonFungibleToken` refer to the same off-chain or on-chain object…”

I was under the impression that the `UniqueIdentifier` was how I ensured that uniqueness:

```
TokenType tokenType = new TokenType("Toyota Corolla", 0);
IssuedTokenType issuedTokenType = new IssuedTokenType(partyA, tokenType);

String VIN = "1G2JB12F047226515";
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
UniqueIdentifier uniqueIdentifier = new UniqueIdentifier(VIN, uuid);

NonFungibleToken nonFungibleToken = new NonFungibleToken(issuedTokenType, partyA, uniqueIdentifier);
```

This allows me to define limitless Toyota Corolla’s each with their own unique `UUID` and Vehicle Identification Number (VIN).

The `MoveNonFungibleTokens()` flow allows me to specify a `QueryCriteria` to isolate the specific `NonFungibleToken` I wish to move (I use a `LinearStateQueryCriteria` specifying the `UUID`):

```
subFlow(new MoveNonFungibleTokens(partyAndToken, observers, queryCriteria));
```

However when I want to redeem a `NonFungibleToken` the `RedeemNonFungibleTokens()` flow only allows me to specify a `TokenType`:

```
subFlow(new RedeemNonFungibleTokens(tokenType, issuer, observers));
```

This means I can’t identify a `NonFungibleToken` by its `UUID`.  If you do what I am doing above you will receive the following error when I try to redeem:

```
Exactly one held token of a particular type TokenType(tokenIdentifier=' Toyota Corolla ', fractionDigits=0) should be in the vault at any one time.
```

If this is the case then `TokenType`’s `tokenIndentifier` ("Toyota Corolla") must be the source of uniqueness.  I would have to do something like this:

```
TokenType tokenType = new TokenType("Toyota Corolla-" + UUID.randomUUID(), 0);
```

Is this correct or have I missed something?

I was just really surprised when I started writing the Redeem parts of my token tests and thought “Well then what is the purpose of the `UniqueIdentifier` in a `NonFungibleToken`?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the case of non-fungible tokens, the relationship between the token type and the token is **one to one**; that's why the redeem flow takes only the `TokenType` parameter.
- Looking at the `MoveNonFungibleTokens` flow input parameters [here](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/master/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/workflows/flows/move/MoveNonFungibleTokensFlow.kt), they sort of contradict the first statement; because even the comment on the flow states that it should be used for one `TokenType` at a time, which means the `queryCriteria` parameter is not needed since you're already specifying the token (token type) that you want to move inside the `PartyAndToken` parameter. I will forward this discussion to R3 engineers to get a clarification.
- As for the your question, the reason you need the unique identifier in the non-fungible token is because it extends `LinearState` (which is identified by that `UUID`).
- Remember that states are immutable in Corda, so how do you mimic an update? You do it buy using a `LinearState`, for instance if your non-fungible token is a car and you want to change the owner of the car (i.e. update the `holder` of the token); then you create a transaction where the input is the current token and the output is the updated token which should have the same `linearId` as the input; this way the output and the input are tied together and now you can track the history of updates of a certain state by querying that shared `linearId`.
- Side note: Your `LinearState` should have 2 constructors; one that assigns a random `linearId` and you should use it when creating a new state, and another constructor that takes a `linearId` as an input parameter; this constructor should be used when you create the output of an update transaction (so you can create the output with the `linearId` of the input), also you must mark that constructor with the `@CordaSerializable` annotation so that Corda uses it when it check-points a certain flow (i.e. serializes then de-serializes your state) otherwise Corda will use the other constructor and assign a new random value for your `linearId` when it de-serializes your state (when the flow resumes) and you essentially end with a different state!
- I recommend that you use `EvolvableTokenType` for your car example instead of `TokenType`; this would allow you to add your custom attributes (VIN, price, mileage, etc...) and you can can control which attributes can be updated (price, mileage) and which cannot (VIN); see more about that in the official free Corda course from R3 [here](https://training.corda.net/).

Comment: Exactly! – It’s the QueryCriteria in the MoveNonFungibleTokens().  I thought it was the key to understanding NonFungibleToken’s i.e. so this is how you can have NonFungibleToken’s built from TokenType’s that have the same TokenIndentifier while still being able to differentiate between them using the LinearState properties (UUID etc.).

If each TokenType has to have a unique TokenIndentifier it makes it difficult to search for "all  the Toyota Corolla's"

It's a question of the design philosophy of NonFungibleToken’s

Appreciate the time you took to write such a thorough answer.